# can't change ImageSource of the image of the plugin of daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms

I am sorry if it is not the best english, I speak spanish. When I want to change the source of the image in a tapped event, the new image only can be seen when a zoom is applied or when the focus of the image (the part of the image that can be seen) is translating. Is there a solution? I am using this nuget https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/ImageCropView

This is the code:

```
<imgcrop:ImageCropView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" x:Name="cropView">
                <imgcrop:ImageCropView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="UpdateImage"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </imgcrop:ImageCropView.GestureRecognizers>
                <imgcrop:ImageCropView.PreviewTransformations>

                    <FFTr:CircleTransformation />
                </imgcrop:ImageCropView.PreviewTransformations>
            </imgcrop:ImageCropView>
```

When a tapped is made the source of the image is change by an activity that returns a stream from a photo of the phone, but the new image can only be seen when the user is applying a zoom or a translation to the image

Comment: Please give more details. Where / How do you set the ImageSource property ? Is the image a byte array / Stream ? ImageCropView is based on FFLoadingImage plugin. Take a look at here (maybe you should use a 'StreamImageSource'): https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/ByteArrayListPageModel.cs#L120-L123

Comment: I set the ImageSource property with a stream